# Can not publish bot to cortana channel

Tags: azure, botframework, cortana-skills-kit

In Azure portal, when click on Channels - Publish to Cortana, it says:
Something went wrong , along with trace Id

1. How can I found out what is wrong using trace id?
2. I created a bot from scratch but same thing happens, is it a Microsoft Azure issue.

Researched online, but no results.

Something went wrong:
TraceId: {}

Comment: First, are you using an MSA for the bot, or a AAD account?

Is this a brand new bot where you reused an invocation name?